# multi site development site showing in google

Tags: multistore, duplicate, robots.txt

I have been testing a multi store environment on Magento 1.9 in the same install that I have my primary live site, and have realized that the content is being indexed twice by Google.  Can I create a robots.txt to prevent the 2nd domain in the multisite from being indexed?

Answer (score 0):

1) Go to Admin > System > Configuration from the current configuration scope dropdown select the site that you don't want to be indexed.

2) Under the general tab select the Design (Make sure your test site is selected in current configuration scope) now in HTML Head section set the  Default Robots as NOINDEX, NOFOLLOW